# Using INSERT INTO SELECT when table structures do not match in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1064

I'm familiar with the following use of the command:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
SELECT * 
  FROM other_table
```

This works fine when the tables are identical in terms of layout.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
SELECT * 
  FROM other_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

This fails with a syntax error:

> MySQL Error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 ON QUERY INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM other_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

I can't find any docs that describe this.

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to do; showing the SQL that doesn't work doesn't make it clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: you cannot do this with 1 query. 1 query - bulk insert, 2 - bulk update.

Comment: @cetver: That is not correct. MySQL allows you to combine bulk insertion and update. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your statement is incomplete:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
SELECT * 
  FROM other_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

The [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) requires that you need to finish the `UPDATE` part by listing which columns to update with which values.

UPDATE:

This ought to work for your particular example:

```
INSERT INTO mytable2 (id, name, `key`)
  SELECT id, name, `key` FROM mytable b
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = b.name
```

The changes are:

- remove the parentheses around the column names in the `SELECT` part.
- quote the column name `key`, since "key" is a reserved word in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, you need to specify which columns that should be updated. It won't update all columns by default (updating primary key for example makes no sense).

Comment: @Ted Hopp: good point. However, can you explain how I'd handle that statement in the given situation? Here's what I've tried and it still fails: 
INSERT INTO  `mytable2` a
SELECT (
`id` ,  `name` ,  `key`
)
FROM  `mytable` b
WHERE 1 ON DUPLICATE 
KEY UPDATE a.name = b.name

Comment: you might need to use the VALUES() function to backreference to values that had been selected, .. KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name)

Comment: @julio - I'm not sure why that wouldn't work. Try listing the target column names explicitly (`INSERT INTO mytable2 (id, name, key) ...`). Also (although I doubt it will help) try using 'name' instead of 'a.name' in the UPDATE clause. What's the error message now?

Comment: @jishi: thanks, tried this but also fails.
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a SELECT (`id`, `name`, `key`) FROM `mytable` b WHERE 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' at line 1 
Query: INSERT INTO `mytable2` a SELECT (`id`, `name`, `key`) FROM `mytable` b WHERE 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a.name=VALUES(name)

Comment: Have you tried specified insert columns aswell? I recall that it might have a bug when using insert into select without column specification.

Comment: @jishi: not sure if this is what you mean, but it too fails:
INSERT INTO `mytable2` a (`id`, `name`, `key`) VALUES SELECT (`id`, `name`, `key`) FROM `mytable` b WHERE 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a.name=VALUES(name)

Comment: Try this: `... UPDATE name=b.name`

Comment: Hi Ted-- same error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a (`id`, `name`, `key`) VALUES SELECT (`id`, `name`, `key`) FROM `mytable` b WHE' at line 1
INSERT INTO  `mytable2` a(
`id` ,
`name` ,
`key`
)
VALUES SELECT (
`id` ,  `name` ,  `key`
)
FROM  `mytable` b

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a complete query that ought to work.

Comment: @Ted-- thanks for all your help. Unfortunately, this made no difference: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a (id, name, `key`) SELECT id, name, `key` FROM mytable b ON DUPLICATE KEY U' at line 1
INSERT INTO mytable2 a(
id,
name,
`key`
)
SELECT id, name,  `key` 
FROM mytable b ON DUPLICATE 
KEY UPDATE name = b.name

Comment: @julio - Sorry about that. I tested a version of my code that did not have an alias for the target table. It turns out that an alias there is not allowed. Try changing `INSERT INTO mytable2 a(...` to `INSERT INTO mytable2 (...`. I've updated (and tested!) the code in my answer.